# Group join and group by linq query

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am new in LINQ and I want to create a simple query. Below is my SQL which I want to convert it into LINQ query in vb.net.

```
 Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT h.head_name as head, sum(d.debit_amount) as debit, sum  (d.credit_amount) as credit " & _
                                    " FROM ((daybook AS d) LEFT JOIN heads AS h ON d.head_id = h.head_id) " & _
                                    " where d.entry_date >= #" & CDate(dtFrom.Value) & "# And d.entry_date <= #" & CDate(dtTo.Value) & "# " & _
                                    " and d.head_id <> 21 " & _
                                    " group by h.head_name " & _
                                    " ORDER BY h.head_name"
```

What I have done is :

```
Dim query = From d In gbl_dsCommonDaybook.Tables(0) _
                      Where CDate(d!entry_date) >= CDate(dtFrom.Value) And CDate(d!entry_date) <= CDate(dtTo.Value) _
                      And CInt(d!head_id) <> HeadID.CashInHand _
                      Group Join h In gbl_dsHeads.Tables(0) On d!head_id Equals h!head_id Into grp = Group _
                      From g In grp.DefaultIfEmpty _
                      Group g By g!head_name Into gh = Group _
                      Order By head_name Ascending _
                      Select New With _
                   {
                       .head = head_name.ToString, _
                       .debit = gh.Sum(Function(s) CSng((s!debit_amount))), _
                       .credit = gh.Sum(Function(s) CSng(s!credit_amount)) _
                   }
```

The error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object comes while executing the query.
I have tried hard to sort it out but of no avail. Please help.

Comment: Check cdate fields if some one is nothing. **EDIT** Gnerally all the convert fields. and gbl_dsCommonDaybook.Tables(0)

Comment: I have checked all the fields, values everything is fine.

Comment: Check also the debit_amount and credit_amount.

Comment: If you put a break point on this line and then `Step Into(F11)` you can step into the individual parts of the query and see where the exception is being thrown and what values are present.

Comment: I am doubtful whether my syntax is correct or not

Comment: I have done two parts of query. First one is working fine but not second. First one :

Comment: group join is having problem. can anyone trace it out or rewrite the query ?

Comment: I partitioned the query in two parts